# How can I update or upgrade BOSS Linux by terminal?

Tags: debian, command-line, terminal, upgrade, jboss

I use *EduBOSS Linux 3.0.* Since installation I still not update my OS. But I want to solve some Audio, Video and Graphics problems. To solve that problems I want update my BOSS Linux. 
**sudo apt-get update**

```
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha Release.gpg
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in eduboss-3.0 Release.gpg
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha Release        
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in eduboss-3.0 Release                           
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/main Sources                          
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/contrib Sources                      
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net anokha Release.gpg                              
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/non-free Sources
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/main i386 Packages                   
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/contrib i386 Packages                
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/non-free i386 Packages               
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net anokha Release                                  
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in eduboss-3.0/main Sources                    
Hit http://packages.bosslinux.in eduboss-3.0/main i386 Packages
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/contrib Translation-sa_IN            
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/contrib Translation-sa               
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/contrib Translation-en
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/main Translation-sa_IN               
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/main Translation-sa                  
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/main Translation-en
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/non-free Translation-sa_IN
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/non-free Translation-sa              
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in anokha/non-free Translation-en              
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in eduboss-3.0/main Translation-sa_IN          
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in eduboss-3.0/main Translation-sa             
Ign http://packages.bosslinux.in eduboss-3.0/main Translation-en             
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net anokha/main Sources                             
  404  Not Found
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release.gpg            
Hit http://dl.google.com stable Release
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net anokha/main i386 Packages
  404  Not Found
Hit http://dl.google.com stable/main i386 Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net anokha/main Translation-sa_IN
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net anokha/main Translation-sa
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net anokha/main Translation-en
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-sa_IN
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-sa
Ign http://dl.google.com stable/main Translation-en
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/dists/anokha/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/dists/anokha/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**How can I update BOSS Linux by terminal only?**

Comment: Contact one of the [support centres](https://www.bosslinux.in/support-centre)...

Answer (score 1):

In the directory /etc/apt/ and /etc/apt/sources.d/ you will found many .list file. Open them as root in vim or nano or gedit and replace all 
'anokha' by 'unnati' and all 'eduboss-3.0' by 'eduboss-4.0'.
Then run,
    sudo apt-get update
if any error occurs, then reboot the system first and then run,
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
But before doing these make sure you are backed up every important document because you are upgrading to the latest release it may cause system break.

Good luck.

Answer (score -2):

write the following command in the terminal "sudo apt-get upgrade". It will upgrade all the packages and install them automatically and after installation is completed restart your computer.

Comment: That is unlikely to work until the `apt-get update` has completed successfully, and the OP is illustrating a situation where it's not.